# how to save the trading- date from get.hist.quote

Tags: r, date, zoo

Hi I download the data with get.hist.quote and with "coredata" I saved the price of spy. Instead, how can I saved the trading date of the periods 2006-12 in a vector?

```
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
SPY <- get.hist.quote("SPY",start = "2006-01-02",end = "2011-01-01",quote = "AdjClose", compression = "d",retclass = c("zoo","ts"))
L<-length(SPY)
SPY <- get.hist.quote("SPY",start = "2006-01-02",end = "2012-01-01",quote = "AdjClose", compression = "d",retclass = c("zoo","ts"))
X <- length(SPY)
```

Comment: Rownames for zoo objects are accessed with the `index` function. Read `help(zoo, pac=zoo)

Comment: they are in number how can I to convert them in date ?

Comment: They are in standard format so `as.Date` would seem the obvious choice.

Comment: the problem is that the if I code as.Date(index(SPY)) they start from 1970...instead  2006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's tested code in support of my comments:

```
dts <- as.Date( index(SPY), origin="2006-01-03")

> str(dts)
 Date[1:1259], format: "2006-01-03" "2006-01-04" "2006-01-05" "2006-01-06" "2006-01-09" "2006-01-10" "2006-01-11" "2006-01-12" "2006-01-13" ...
> max(dts)
[1] "2010-12-31"
```

Comment: I did as you but I ve dts <- as.Date( index(SPY), origin="2006-01-02")
> str(dts)
 Date[1:1511], format: "2006-01-03" "2006-01-04" "2006-01-05" "2006-01-06" "2006-01-09" "2006-01-10" ...
> max(dts)
[1] "2011-12-30"

Comment: dts <- as.Date( index(SPY), origin="2006-01-02")
> str(dts)
 Date[1:1511], format: "2006-01-03" "2006-01-04" "2006-01-05" "2006-01-06" "2006-01-09" "2006-01-10" ...
> max(dts)
[1] "2011-12-30"

Comment: your results is correct I don't understand why I have 1511 column